# Odd behavior of Numpy any() when dtype=object

Tags: python, numpy

Numpy [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) on `any()` says "*A new boolean or ndarray is returned...*" and "*Returns single boolean if axis is None.*"

Consider this:

```
>>> np.array([0, 111, 222]).any()
True
>>> np.array([0, 111, 222], dtype=object).any()
111
```

Axis is None, but a boolean is not returned in the second case. It can be admitted, though, that the result is truthy.

The problem comes when a subsequent logical operation is performed. For example:

```
>>> np.invert(np.array([0, 111, 222]).any())
False
>>> np.invert(np.array([0, 111, 222], dtype=object).any())
-112
```

This can be easily circumvented, once you realize how `any()` behaves on when using `dtype=object`.

But the question remains: Is this the expected behavior of `any()`? Shouldn't it return a boolean as the docs say?

Comment: I guess the object version behaves like python's `0 or 111 or 222`

Comment: This seems to be a bug in code or documentation.

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues

It's on Github if a bug's been found.

Comment: Math operations on object dtype arrays are known to be hit-or-miss.  I can't say exactly what's going on here, but I'm not surprised. The sequential python `or` is consistent with what I've see for other operators.